# How to send a radio button and a checkbox value from a html form?

Tags: php, html, checkbox, radio-button, forms

I'm creating a form with select, input, radio buttons and checkboxes and others.
Part of the code where is the part of my question is like this:

**formulario.html**

```html
<form action="suporte_email.php" method="post" name="formulario" id="formulario" >

    <div class="conjunto7" id="conjunto7">
         <label for="garantia">Garantia</label><br>
           <div>
        <input id="radio1" type="radio" name="radio"  value="Sim">
           <label for="radio1"><span><span></span></span> Sim </label>
        </div>
        
        
           <div>
          <input id="radio2" type="radio" name="radio"  value="Não">
           <label for="radio2"><span><span></span></span> Não </label>
        </div>
    </div>
        
        <br><br><br><br>
        
    <div class="conjunto8" id="conjunto8">
         <label for="contrato">Contrato</label><br>
            <div>
           <input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" name="checkbox"  value="Sim">
            <label for="checkbox1"><span></span> Sim </label>
         </div>
                  
         <div>
           <input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox" name="checkbox"  value="Não">
         <label for="checkbox2"><span></span> Não </label>
         </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

**suporte_email.php**

```
//Get Data
$nome = $_POST['nome'];                    
$empresa = $_POST['empresa'];              
$contacto = $_POST['contacto'];            
$email = $_POST['email'];                  
$marca = $_POST['marca'];                   
$other = $_POST['other'];                    
$serial_number = $_POST['serial_number'];     
$garantia = $_POST['garantia'];               
$contrato = $_POST['contrato'];             
$permissoes = $_POST['permissoes'];           
$descricao_avaria = $_POST['descricao_avaria'];
$checkbox = $_POST['checkbox'];
$radio = $_POST['radio'];

   // Parse/Format/Verify Data
   $to      = "teste@gmail.com"; 
   $from    = '';
   $subject = "Formulário de Suporte";

   $email_body = "$crlf De: $nome$crlf Email: $email$crlf Assunto: $subject$crlf$crlf Empresa: $empresa$crlf Contacto: $contacto$crlf Marca: $marca$crlf Outra: $other$crlf Número de Série: $serial_number$crlf Garantia: $garantia$crlf Contrato: $contrato$crlf Tipo de Suporte: $permissoes$crlf$crlf Descrição da Avaria: $descricao_avaria";

   // Setup EMAIL headers, particularly to support UTF-8
   // We set the EMAIL headers here, these will be sent out with your message
   // for the receiving email client to use.
   $headers = 'From: ' . $from  . $crlf .
           'Reply-To: ' . $email  . $crlf .
           'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8' .  $crlf .
           'Para: Website'  .  $to . $crlf .
           'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();


   // Then we pass the headers into our mail function
   mail($to, $subject, $email_body, $headers);
   header('Location: agradecimentos.html');

}
```

Basically the variables from the radio button and from the checkbox don't appear when I receive the email. I want to receive the selected value from the radio and from the checkbox.

**P:S:** Also tried to change where is `$garantia` for `$radio` and where is `$contrato` for `$checkbox`.

Comment: Your radios and check boxes are overwriting each other on POST. You need to have field names such as `name="checkbox[]"` - so that you can post an array. Then, in PHP, you can access them via `$_POST['checkbox']` or implode them into a single string `implode(", ", $_POST['checkbox'])`

Comment: @HalfCrazed so i changed the name where name="radio" i put name="radio[]" and where is name="checkbox" i put name="checkbox" right?                                                                                                                      I'm going to try run that code and tell u if worked :D thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much for the help  @HalfCrazed but i made the code with foreach and it still doesn't send the email with the value of radio and checkbox.

Answer (score 2):

Your checkboxes have the same name:

```
<input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" name="checkbox"  value="Sim">
<input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox" name="checkbox"  value="Não">
```

That means the LAST checkbox in the form is the one whose value is set in $_POST.

Duplicate names are acceptable for radio buttons, because they're an `OR`-type select - only one single radio button in a group can be selected. But checkboxes are an `AND` - you can select multiple checkboxes, which means each one has to have a unique name.

Alternatively, you can use PHP's array-name hack:

```
<input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]"  value="Não">
                                                    ^^---
```

which tells PHP to expect multiple different values for the same field name, and it'll produce an array in $_POST of each of those values.

Comment: Ok,i didn't noticed that :p thank you very much.  My other question is concerned with the .php because the values appear empty when sended. So, for the radio button i can use the same name="radio[]" right?

Comment: In PHP, your posted values will be arrays... so, `foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $value) echo $value;` -- you need to figure out what to do with the data, however.. Also, like my other comment on your question, you could implode the values into a single string if necessary.

Comment: for the radio buttons, it's not necessary. you're not allowed to select more than one radio button in a `name=...` set, so only one value (should) ever get sent to the server.